# Multiple bibiographies using biblatex, and resetting numbers

Tags: biblatex, numbering, subdividing

I am writing a sort of large CV, and I've split my publications into several blocks, using this:

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[title={Publications}]
\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=subbibliography,
title={Printed Sources},resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subbibliography,
title={Online Sources},resetnumbers=true]
```

which I mostly copied from the `biblatex` manual.  However, the numbers aren't being reset as I want.  The numbers in the Online Sources part, for example, go [13], [21], [29], [36] instead of [1], [2], [3], [4] as I'd like them to.

Probably there are options better suited to my purpose than `resetnumbers`, but I haven't found them yet.  Basically I want each sub-bibliography to be numbered starting at [1], and increasing in increments of 1.  Ideas or advice?

Comment: You have to load `biblatex` with the option `defernumbers=true` if you want to specify `resetnumbers=true` when printing bibliographies.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem: it will help us to see if @karlkoeller's suggestion is the one needed here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use the option `resetnumbers=true` when printing specific bibliographies, you have to define the option `defernumbers=true` globally.

This means that you have to load `biblatex` with the mentioned option, e.g.

```
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

MWE just to test it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[title={Publications}]
\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=subbibliography,
title={Printed Sources},resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subbibliography,
title={Online Sources},resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

Output with `defernumbers=true`

[image]

and without it

[image]

Comment: I am using modernCV class and using both `defernumbers=true' and `resetnumbers=true`  at appropriate locations but still the numbering for my bibliography is still not reset. Is there any issue/conflict with modernCV package or am I doing something wrong, ```\section{Referred Journals  Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article, heading=none, resetnumbers=true]```