# I need two separate bibliographies at the end of my document

Tags: multibib

I'd like to write a report which cites some of my own publications and also publications from others; and I would like to separate the lists at the end of the report.

I used `multibib` in the past, but now I encounter problems since I've added the `hyperref` package. I read that `multibib` is not very reliable — and that `hyperref` is rather sensitive.

Is there someone who could advise me about any other useful bib package, like `chapterbib` or any other? Or, on the converse, is `multibib` reliable and fully compatible — in which case I made some poor use of it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you loading `hyperref` *after* `multibib`? Can you share a small example of code that shows the issue?

Comment: You can use `biblatex`  - it supports multiple bibliographies filtered by sections or keywords or what have you. But `biblatex` does not work with BibTeX's `.bst` styles, it has its own system of styles. So you would need to be more precise about what you want.

Comment: Here are some questions that may be of some help. [Multibib reverse label or sort order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/multibib-reverse-label-or-sort-order/37850#37850), [Two bibliographies with two different styles in the same document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document) and [Multiple bibiographies using biblatex, and resetting numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128959/multiple-bibiographies-using-biblatex-and-resetting-numbers)